# How can I map a prototype function to an array of objects that have that prototype?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript to get a handle on a object prototype function with the this guaranteed to be the object in question?  I particularly got to a PITA situation when I wanted to map an array of objects of the proper type to such a function.  This ended up being Window. Yes I did pull the function itself from the proper place but internally it refers to 'this'. I know about call and apply but not how you might use them to handle this sort of situation.

Is there a way short of an explicit loop instead of using map?  Oddly it apparently does not do the same thing re 'this' as

```
object_with_the_prototype.some_prototype_function()
```

would do if instead I have

```
[object_with_the_prototype].map(this.some_prototype_function)
```

How come?

Answer (score 0):

if your method expects one argument, then it's easy. If you need more than one argument, or more importantly, not a number as a 2nd argument (think .toString), then you can use bind to curry this into the 1st argument:

```
"a,b,c".split(",").map( Function.call.bind(  "".big  )  );
```

in your code:

```
[object_with_the_prototype]
  .map( Function.call.bind( thisObject.some_prototype_function ) );
```

if your method calls like x(a,b,c), the bound function calls like x(this, a, b, c)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
[object_with_the_prototype].map(function(thisObject) {
    thisObject.some_prototype_function();
} );
```

Comment: that doesn't let you pass any arguments, and why type out "return" if you don't have to...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see it.  The problem is that in the array case I was mistakenly assuming that the normal  walk from the object up its prototype chain would happen although I was giving it an explicit function to map to.  I fixed it by defining a function taking an element from the array and calling the desired prototype function through that element.  I map to that function instead.

```
function do_one(element) {element.some_prototype_function()}
[object_with_prototype].map(do_one)
```